# Match multiple columns in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I want to match three different columns in different sheets in Excel.

In one sheet I have Group and Name, and in another I have Name and Email. 
How do I match Name in Sheet 1 with Email in Sheet 2?

```
Sheet 1
Group Name 
A     John    
B     Jack    
C     Anne    

Sheet 2
Name  Email
John  john@
Jack  jack@
Anne  anne@
```

Comment: What do you mean by match? Match how? You want to combine them? You want to highlight matching ones? You want to paste a new value for in a row somewhere?

Comment: why not match both names?

Comment: Combine is probably the word I'm looking for. Maybe create a new sheet with Group, Name, Email...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Sheet2 column C`, add a `Group` with this formula copied and dragged down:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$B$4,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4,0),1)
```

[image]

See the pic above.  This should give what you are looking for.

Comment: I can't get the formula to work. Just get a generic error message. Did it work for you?

Comment: @ian0411 Just a point to make about index, you only need to index the results that you want to return so you can make a 1 dimensional array as opposed to a 2 dimensional 1: `=Index(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!:$B$2:$B$4,0))`, this will have performance impacts over a large DataSet

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor, you are correct.  I didn't pay much attention to this but obviously it can be avoided with thorough code review.  Thank you.

Comment: @Jonfo, sorry that I didn't notice you have replied.  Yes, it worked for me as you can see the screenshot.  What error did you see?  You can edit your question to post a screenshot there so we can better assist you.

Comment: @ian0411, I fixed the error, but get #N/A instead.  

When I evaluate the formula I get the following steps:  
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4:MATCH(”John”;Sheet1!$B$2:$B$4;0))  
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4;#N/A)

Comment: You can try to change the formula to this first: `=INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH(TRIM(D2),$B$2:$B$4,0))`.  If this doesn't work, that means you probably have the empty spaces entered in the group list.  To check that, you can try `=LEN(A1)` and see if you agree with the length of the text.  If that group list data can not be changed, you will then use this array formula (click `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` together) `=INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH(TRIM(D2),TRIM($B$2:$B$4),0))` to fix the problem.